# Firebase Background Notifications with Rest API in React Native

Tags: react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase, react-native-push-notification

I am new to react native and creating an app that displays a list of events that have been stored in a database and converted to a json format using php. I then use a restful api to be able to display them within my react native app.

I would like to display background notifications each time a new event has been added.

After doing some research I have found that the best way to send background notifications is to use firebase. I have been able to get my code to send background messages on my iOS device, when I run a test notification from the firebase console.

Here is my set up code

```js
const getFcmToken = async () => {
  const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
  if (fcmToken) {
      console.log("Your Firebase Token is:", fcmToken);
  } else {
      console.log("Failed", "No Token Recived");
  }
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
    const enabled =
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
      authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;
      if (enabled) {
        getFcmToken();
        console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
      }
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
      await this.requestUserPermission();

       // Register background handler
       messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
       console.log('Messaage handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
    });
  };
}
```

After doing some more research I found that the best way to send notifications without having to use the firebase console is to create a RESTful API.

I followed an online tutorial on how to do this but am unsure how to get it to work in the background and there doesn't seem to be any tutorials on this.

Here is my code.

```js
export const sendPushNotifications = async () => {
  const FIREBASE_API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxx";
  const message = {
    registration_ids: [
      "xxxxxxxxxx"
    ],

    notification: {
      title: "This is a Notification",
      boby: "This is the body of the Notification",
      vibrate: 1,
      sound: 1,
      show_in_foreground: true,
      priority: "high",
      content_available: true,
    },
    data: {
      title: "This is a Notification",
      boby: "This is the body of the Notification",
      score: 50,
      wicket: 1,

    },
  }
  
  let headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    Authorization: "key=" + FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  })

  let response = await fetch ("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",{
    method: "POST",
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(message),
  })
  response = await response.json();
  console.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no api key it need ServerKey
on Console - Setting - Cloud Messaging tab

Answer (score -1):

try these events in `componentDidMount`

```
// when app is in background and clicked
messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
      console.log(
        'Notification caused app to open from background state:',
        remoteMessage.notification,
      );
    });

// when app is in closed and clicked
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
          );
        }
      });
```

source : https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications

Comment: sadly these didn't help, this would mean I would still have to send my notification through the firebase console which I don't want